# CHAQUOPY - Convert Python Object to Kotlin class

Tags: python, java, android, kotlin, chaquopy

In the python file:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, name, costs):
        self.name = name
        self.costs = costs

def returnObj(string):
    card = Card(string, 2)
    return card
```

In the Kotlin file:

```
val pyObject = pythonFile.callAttr("returnObj", "string")
```

How could I convert that python object into a kotlin class? I don't know how to use the method .toJava(Class), I tried to put there a kotlin class with the same attributes as the python object but it gives me an error "Not enough information to infer type variable T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaquopy doesn't support converting between classes on the basis of identical attribute names. However, it easily supports creating Kotlin/Java objects directly from Python code.

For example, if your Kotlin class is `com.example.Card`, then you can replace your whole Python `Card` class with the line `from com.example import Card`, and `returnObj` will still work fine.

Then in Kotlin, you can write this:

```kotlin
val card = pythonFile.callAttr("returnObj", "string").toJava(Card::class.java)
```